# Change Lodash delimiters with Yeoman

Tags: node.js, yeoman, lodash

I can't understend how I can change Lodash delimiters when using Yeoman scaffolder.

I need to change the default delimiters `<%= something %>` with new delimiters `___something___`. It's possible do this change to Lodash templating?

Comment: What is the usecase for that? Anyway, you can have a look at this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/escape-delims And this pr: https://github.com/yeoman/generator/pull/489

Comment: I can not understand how to use this package that you suggest. Changing the delimiters as the PR says works, but when I use delimiters that doesn't start with an angle bracket it seems that Lodash doesn't recognize them as delimiters.